# Numba error: "LoweringError: Failed at nopython (nopython mode backend)"

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I'm trying to optimize a Python class using the numba class decorator.  I read the online instructions for the numba @jitclass [guide](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/jitclass.html).  I need help figuring out what i'm doing wrong.

The class initializes an NxN Rubik's cube instantiated in a numpy array.  The step method twists the bottom cube face 90 degrees clockwise.  This class runs fine without the decorator but fails with it.  Thanks.

```
from numba import jitclass
from numba import int32, int16, float32
import numpy as np

spec = [
    ('value', int16[:, :, ::1]),
    ('cube_dim', int16),
    ('c', int16[:, :, ::1]),
    ('slice1d', int16[::1]),
    ('slice2d', int16[:, ::1]),
    ('slice3d', int16[:, :, ::1])
]


@jitclass(spec)
class ncube:
    def __init__(self, cube_dim):
        self.cube_dim = cube_dim
        c = np.zeros(self.cube_dim * self.cube_dim, dtype=np.int16).reshape(self.cube_dim, self.cube_dim)
        c = np.concatenate((c, c + 1, c + 2, c + 3, c + 4, c + 5), axis=0).reshape(6, self.cube_dim, self.cube_dim)
        self.value = c

    def step(self, move):
        if move == 'D':
            # rotate F,B,L,R
            slice1d = self.value[[0, 1, 4, 5], self.cube_dim - 1, :].reshape(4 * self.cube_dim)
            slice2d = np.roll(slice1d, self.cube_dim).reshape(4, self.cube_dim)
            self.value[[0, 1, 4, 5], self.cube_dim - 1, :] = slice2d
            # rot D 90 degrees
            slice2d = self.value[3, :, :]
            np.rot90(slice2d, 1)
            self.value[3, :, :] = slice2d

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.value)


c1 = ncube(3)
c1.step('D')
print(c1)
```

End of error Traceback:

```
numba.errors.LoweringError: Failed at nopython (nopython mode backend)

File "test1.py", line 21
[1] During: lowering "(self).value = c.1" at /Users/ericadar/test1.py (21)
[2] During: resolving callee type: jitclass.ncube#7fc6c59146b8<value:array(int16, 3d, C),cube_dim:int16,c:array(int16, 3d, C),slice1d:array(int16, 1d, C),slice2d:array(int16, 2d, C),slice3d:array(int16, 3d, C)>
[3] During: typing of call at <string> (3)
--%<-----------------------------------------------------------------

File "<string>", line 3
>>>
```

Comment: I think it has to do with your indexing in the step function. 

From Numba docs:

"Arrays support normal iteration. Full basic indexing and slicing is supported. A subset of advanced indexing is also supported: only one advanced index is allowed, and it has to be a one-dimensional array (it can be combined with an arbitrary number of basic indices as well)."

Comment: commenting out the step method doesn't help - i get the same error.  the trace seems to point to `self.value = c` as the problem line, but there is no indexing or subsetting for this assignment.  I'm simply copying c into self.value and I defined both the same way in spec.

Comment: I got it to compile by removing your  np.concatenate() .... line

Comment: thanks, I'll try it.  Oddly it looks like `np.concatenate` is supported by numba: https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/numpysupported.html